# Sorting the x axes in R

Tags: r, sorting, plot, multiple-axes

I built a logistic regression model (called 'mylogit') using the glm function in R as follows:

```
mylogit <- glm(answer ~ as.factor(gender) + age, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
```

where age is numeric and gender is categorical (male and female).

I then proceeded to make predictions with the model built.

```
pred <- predict(mylogit, type = "response")
```

I can easily make a time series plot of the predictions by doing:

```
plot.ts(ts(pred))
```

to give a plot that looks like this:

[Plot of Time against Predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUO0W.jpg)

which gives a plot of the predictions.

My question is this:
Is it possible to put the x axis in segments according to gender (male or female) which was specified in the glm?  In other words, can I have predictions on the y axis and have gender (divided into male and female) on the x axis?

A sample of the data I want to plot from is similar to this:

I did:

```
bind = cbind(mydata, pred)
```

'bind' looks like this:

```
pred          age        gender
0.9461198     32          male
0.9463577     45         female
0.9461198     45         female
0.9461198     37         female
0.9477645     40          male
0.8304513     32         female
```

Comment: So basically you want to sort the x-axis, not add any additional axes? In that case I think you should change the title of the question.

Comment: Great, could you also add a small sample dataset, e.g. with `dput(head(mydata))`? I guess the problem is that the object you get from `ts(pred)` is already sorted in some random unwanted way, but it is hard to tell without having the same data as you. Perhaps sorting `mydata` based on gender before modelling with `glm` might solve the problem even.

Comment: @Backlin I've added a sample of the data set to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `ts` and `plot.ts` because the data you have is not a time series, right? Just sort `pred` before plotting.

```
# Get data
str <- "pred,age,gender
0.9461198,32,male
0.9463577,45,female
0.9461198,45,female
0.9461198,37,female
0.9477645,40,male
0.8304513,32,female"
bind <- read.csv(textConnection(str))

# Plot
bind <- bind[order(bind$gender),]
plot(bind$pred, col = bind$gender)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(bind, aes(x = gender, y = pred)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = .3))
```

Or without creating `bind` you could do `plot(pred[order(mydata$gender)])`.

Comment: great insight. The question will then be how to identify which is male or female on the x axis, and also label them accordingly.

Comment: You could colour the points by gender or do a grouped dotplot (see the updated answer).

Comment: you are a genius in data analysis

Answer (score 1):

Check out #4 on [this blog post](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/15-questions-about-r-plots), "4. How To Create Two Different X- or Y-axes".

My suggestion to you is that you look at some of the dedicated R plotting tools, like [ggplot2](http://ggplot2.org).

Comment: Note that in ggplot it is actively discouraged to have multiple axis and quite the trick to achieve - see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right

Comment: `ggplot2` won't help you here. Being based on the [grammar of graphics](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387245447), it considers any graph requiring multiple axes to be inherently flawed in its design. You have to stick with base graphics as far as I know.

Comment: Good points about ggplot theory and execution. I suggested ggplot precisely because it does have a very specific way of doing things, i.e., a framework, and one that helps you think about how you're going to use R well.